# What is the purpose of the 3rd on-screen button on a button-less phone?

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, buttons, 4.1-jelly-bean

I haven't used Ice Cream Sandwich yet and as far as I know, some phones (Google Nexus perhaps) don't have capacitive or hard buttons. Now as you can see below, there's 4 buttons (this was an image I found while googling).

[image: Android 4.0 navigation bar]

As far as I know, the buttons are (starting from the left):

- Back button
- Home button
- ???
- Menu button

I want to know what the third one is? The one that has overlapping rectangles? My phone has capacitive and I have all the above aside from that one button. I asked this just out of curiosity.

Comment: looks like the menu button, don't know about the 3 doted one

Comment: The third dotted one IS the menu button. Not the rectangle one

Comment: a little bit of dabbling the google revealed to me that this is, actually, the task manager/recent apps button

Comment: @svarog oh wow, how did you come across that info? I don't know what search tags to use when searching xD

Comment: FYI: what you called *"physical soft buttons"* are called capacitive buttons.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That's the "Recent Apps" button. It's alternative of long-press physical home button.

If you tap this, a scrollable screen appears containing thumbnails of suspended or closed recent apps. You can tap thumbnails to switch to apps or swipe it to discard.

Comment: But why separate that? Does holding down the "virtual" home button no longer show the recent apps? (I need to wait 3 more minutes to accept ur answer. :P)

Comment: @Shedo Ask user experience department of Google. Probably, they want to show off multitasking.. or, they want us to get to multitasking without wasting any moment by long-press.

Comment: @ShedoSurashu: that is correct, long pressing the home button no longer does anything currently. I think the UI team is discouraging long pressing in the recent versions of Android. Long pressing is horrible from usability point of view since they are not discoverable.