# Customize on-screen function buttons on Insignia Flex tablet

Tags: customization, buttons

We just bought an inexpensive, low-end Android Tablet (the Insignia Flex 8") running Android 6.0.  The navigation bar buttons (which are also called, apparently, the "Home Touch buttons", "On-Screen Virtual Buttons", are the default set of three: Back, Home and Overview buttons (the same set shown in [What is the offical name of the third on-screen button?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/32697/what-is-the-offical-name-of-the-third-on-screen-button)).

Now, my LG K7 phone (running 5.1.1) also came with the same default set of buttons, but they are customizable:  by going to Settings > Display > Home touch buttons > Button combination I can choose up to 5 buttons to include in that row.  I can't figure out, though, if there is a comparable setting in the Insignia Flex. Is there a way to customize those buttons?

The device, by the way, is *not* rooted, and I prefer to keep it that way.  I am looking for a way to do this using only the built-in features of the device.

Comment: Unrooted then guess not. Android only introduced native navbar customization in Android 7.x, and even that is normally not accessible (only via terminal commands).

Comment: Interesting - so is it unusual that my phone has navbar customization as a native feature?

Comment: It's not "native". Manufacturers create customizations all they want and embed it in their UI/UX. Insignia doesn't - it just used near-vanilla Android, likely out of cost concerns.

Comment: Sorry, I guess I meant "pre-loaded".