# What is the official name of the "open apps" view that is navigated to by hitting the square system button?

Tags: system, user-interface

On Android, there are three buttons along the bottom system bar. When I hit the square one, a UI displaying all the currently "open" apps.

What is the official name of this view?

Comment: Related: https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/32697/what-is-the-offical-name-of-the-third-on-screen-button

Comment: Despite its seldomly-used formal name (Recents Screen), I generally refer to it as "Recents Apps" or "Recently Open", as it shows your recently open apps.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's called [Recents Screen](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/recents):

> The Recents screen (also referred to as the Overview screen, recent task list, or recent apps) is a system-level UI that lists recently accessed activities and tasks.